# I can't delete a post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to destroy a post (Photo) in rails but it keeps directing to the show'page of the post.

views/photos/index.html.erb

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', photo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

routes

```
  resources :photos
  resources :billets

  devise_for :users
  get 'information/index'
  get 'information/afficher'

  root to: 'information#index'

  get "*path" => redirect("/")
```

logs right when I click on Destroy in the Photo' index

```
Started GET "/photos/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-23 19:13:22 -0400
Processing by PhotosController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Photo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `photos`.* FROM `photos`  WHERE `photos`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
------------    With this action I will SHOW the given Photo------  
  Rendered photos/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 9.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

my destroy action

```
  def destroy
      puts "With this action I will destroy the given Photo"
    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to photos_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: It sounds to me like the Javascript that ensures that clicking the link results in a `DELETE` isn’t running. Without the `method: :delete`, it’s just a link to the `show` action. Is the confirmation dialog popping up?

Comment: no the confirmation is not popping

Comment: Okay, so that supports my theory. The same code that makes the link perform a `DELETE` is the code that creates the confirmation popup ([jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)). Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Do you have `//= require jquery_ujs
` in your `application.js`?

Comment: my application.js got this `//= require jquery_ujs`
`//= require ckeditor-jquery`
`//= require locales/jquery.timeago.fr.js`
`//= require jquery-fileupload`.. thanks I was missing jquery....

Comment: `//= require jquery` now I have added this and it's working... you could post an answer I will vote up for you Buck!

Comment: Done. If you mark the answer as accepted, other people won’t come here, wondering if your question is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code that makes the link perform a DELETE is the code that creates the confirmation popup ([jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)). If the popup isn’t showing, the UJS code must not be working. Do you have the right require statements in your `application.js`?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: To add to this, the `delete` HTTP verb is applied to the request by Rails with Javascript. Hence if you include JQuery, it should solve the issue

Answer (score -2):

You're redirecting to the photos_url.

```
  format.html { redirect_to photos_url }
```

You can do a bunch of stuff here, like request.referer, another path from your rake routes output, or manually determine where to go depending on the params you get in the destroy action

Comment: There’s no problem with redirecting to `photos_url`. The problem the person described is that clicking the link wasn’t even deleting the model, but instead going to the `show` action.